# How to set fixed price when creating bundle product in magento

Tags: magento

Like the title, how can I create a bundle product with price_type > fixed in Magento through API. I've tried

```
price_type : 'fixed'
price_type : 1
```

but it doesn't work, the product is still created with dynamic `price_type`

Magento version: 1.7 CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. There are two problems you take care of when you create a new bundle item.

1. Set price_type when creating an bundle item will create an index so the item is displayed correctly on front end
2. Change it second time `price_type => 1 // fixed or 0 // dynamic` when you update the product ( using the api )

Comment: I know this is old but what do you mean. can you show some code for that second step. Because from what i see you can't update the price type after creating a bundle product in the front end so where and how would you do so???